# How to download and keep local copy of google photos album on android phone

Tags: google-photos

Is there a way to mark that a local copy of an album should be preserved (on an android phone)? If not what is the easiest way to download the album locally? (3rd party tools?)

Is there any other photo backing up service that does have this functionality?

Comment: "what is the easiest way to download the album locally?":   https://takeout.google.com ?

Comment: @Luuk, that does not seem particularly easy. It requires downloading everything right and not one album. Also it will lead to problems with google photos when I use these to put an album on my phone's storage because it will try to back them up again right? And since you have to download everything each time it seems like it would be super complicated to keep an album up to date.

Comment: But it is the **easiest** way, I did not claim it was easy.... 

Comment: Had a look at [locked folder](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/10694388?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cthe-difference-between-locked-folder-archive%2Cwhat-you-can-do-with-items-in-your-locked-folder%2Chow-locked-folder-items-count-towards-your-storage-quota%2Cwhy-you-may-find-copies-of-locked-folder-items-in-other-areas-of-photos%2Clearn-about-your-eligibility-for-locked-folder)?

Comment: @beeshyams, that seems counter intuitive to use (since it seems for hiding private photos) but it might work in the future. For now it has the problem that you cannot backup the locked folder in the cloud (a backup for the locked folder seems to be coming though, with some users already having access to it). For now as a work around I guess you could copy the album to have it both as a normal album (so that it gets backed up) and as a hidden folder. This does seem like it would have tedious synchronization issues.